# how to use awesomium sdk in linux

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop, awesomium

i have downloaded awesomium sdk for linux 64 bit system, now i want to run a simple hello world application in monodevelop that opens the hello world message in awesomium, how to use this sdk in linux...Plz give me some suggestions.

Regards 
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the SDK, extract it to a folder in your home directory.
Open the Terminal.
Change directories to the SDK files you just extracted.
Run **sudo make all** to install the library to your machine.

T0 check whether it Installed and working

Change directories to the ./bin and RUN

**./awesomium_sample_hello**